# How to send pre-determined bit of text to REPL with Vim-Slime with a shortcut?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm learning Lisp, using Vim as my editor. (Please don't tell me to switch to Emacs. You are wasting our time.)

I'm using the lovely plug-in vim-slime to send parts of my code over to the REPL after I modify it.

I would like to be able to set up a shortcut to send `abort` to my REPL window, because when my code generates an error, I have to go over to the REPL and type `abort` in there, et cetera. I know I could type it into the code window, highlight it, and then hit the slime shortcut keys, but that seems a like wayayay too much work for someone using Vim.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Bases on the readme, it’s unclear if there’s an exposes way to send text to the repl *without* typing it. (This is why my plugins tend to just expose functions and leave you to set up mappings—my own [simpl](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl) is one example; tim pope’s fireplace has another interesting model—the repl is less visible.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like figuring it out yourself:

```
:nnoremap <C-A> :call slime#send("abort\n") <CR>
```